# JTextField in JFrame uneditable when using JCEF in JInternalFrame until JFrame loses focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, chromium-embedded

I have started implementing [JCEF](https://github.com/jcefbuild/jcefbuild) in a project of mine, and I am initializing the embedded browser in a `JInternalFrame` inside of a `JFrame`, alongside a series of form fields on a `JPanel` next to the `JInternalFrame`. The browser component doesn't fully initialize until the `JFrame` actually becomes visible, and I'm finding that my `JTextField`s are uneditable unless the `JFrame` loses and regains focus.

Any idea of what could be happening and how to fix it? This only happens when using a `JInternalFrame` with the JCEF component...

It also happens every time I call `loadURL` to load a new page in the browser: the `JTextField`s become uneditable again, until I lose/gain focus in the `JFrame`.

---

**UPDATE**:
I have found a hack which allows the `JTextField`s to become editable again, but I wouldn't call it a solution because it is not very elegant. I added a load handler to the CefClient instance ( `client.addLoadHandler(new CefLoadHandlerAdapter())`  ) with an `@Ovveride` on the `onLoadingStateChange` method, which in turn gives access to the current browser component. From there I can detect when loading in the browser is complete, and use SwingUtilities to get the Window that the browser component is in. Then I `setVisible(false)` and `setVisible(true)` on that Window. I say it's not a solution because every time the browser is done loading the Window disappears and reappears. Even though the `JTextField`s are editable again, it is quite ugly to see the window flashing. I've tried all kinds of `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods to no avail, unless I didn't call them right...

```java
client.addLoadHandler(new CefLoadHandlerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStateChange(CefBrowser browser, boolean isLoading,
                                boolean canGoBack, boolean canGoForward) {
      if (!isLoading) {
            //browser_ready = true;
            System.out.println("Browser has finished loading!");
            SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( browser.getUIComponent() ).setVisible(false);
            SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( browser.getUIComponent() ).setVisible(true);
      }
    }
});
```

If anyone can suggest a better solution, please do!

Comment: Looks like you're running a long-running process on the Swing EDT (event dispatch thread) and this may be blocking the same thread from functioning. If so, then consider using a SwingWorker to perform the long-running task within a background thread.

Comment: I had the same hunch so I have just tried implementing a SwingWorker at least to handle the subsequent `browser.loadURL()` calls (I'm not sure how I can control the first render on Window open). But even with the `loadURL()` process delegated to the SwingWorker, the `JTextField`s still become uneditable. No other components become uneditable or unresponsive, just the JTextFields. I tried calling `jTextField1.revalidate()` at the end of the SwingWorkers background work but that didn't help; I tried `jTextField1.setEditable(false); jTextField1.setEditable(true);` but that didn't help...

Comment: Just to clarify, the "editable" property is still set to true, and hover and focus are working properly. The JTextField is de facto uneditable even though "editable" is still set to true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem by studying the sample JCEF application a little better. I need to implement a FocusHandler in order to release the embedded browser's hold on keyboard input:

```java
private boolean browserFocus_ = true;
---
jTextField1.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
      if (!browserFocus_) return;
      browserFocus_ = false;
      KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().clearGlobalFocusOwner();
      jTextField1.requestFocus();
    }
});
```